# Setting UIView position and size

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

When creating a new `UIView` or panning/swiping a view to a new position, whats the proper way of setting the new position and size.  Currently, to move views resulting from a pan/swipe action, I'm using ratios based on the original position of the view that I'm moving and its relation to other views and items (navigation bar).

When moving a view due to a swipe I do the following:

```
CGFloat swipeUpDelta = -1 *(self.view.bounds.size.height - (self.view.bounds.size.height - recordView.frame.origin.y) - (self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height + ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height)));

[UIView animateWithDuration:.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    recordView.frame = CGRectOffset(recordView.frame, 0, swipeUpDelta);
} completion:nil];
```

Or creating a view that renders a sineWave across my viewcontroller:

```
self.sineWave = [[OSDrawWave alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1*self.view.bounds.size.width, (.75*self.view.bounds.size.height), 2*self.view.bounds.size.width, .3125*(2*self.view.bounds.size.width))];
```

Everything works fine, but I wanted to know if there is a better way of doing these things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. `initWithFrame:` or `myView.frame` is considered the correct way of positioning a UIView. Using `animateWithDuration:` with a new frame size is also pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you mean as well. When you move a UIView you can move the view a variety of ways, it depends on your code and what you want out of it. The below is a valid example of code to move a CALayer inside of a UIView to follow touch positions. You can use this, you can animate your view, you can use explicit animations when changing the position of the layer or center of the view (By default iOS animates any changed property values of a CALayer... you can ride off of this and enable this feature for UIViews if you please). If you're moving a UIView, it's a good idea to move the view according to the center property. This is pretty much how SpriteKit works and any high functioning animation engine (avoid always resetting the frame... especially if you don't need to).

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self];
    boxLayer.position = p;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self];
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    boxLayer.position = p;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

As a note, note the comment in the following line of code

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
/*UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self]; // this causes the animations to appear sluggish as there is a consistant change in destination location. The above code corrects this. 
[boxLayer setPosition:p];*/
```

This is valid, and may provide the results you want... it all depends on what you want.